# `docker images --digests` with and without tag give different answers

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to figure out how to determine the digest of an image on my local machine.

If I ask `docker images` to tell me about the digests for my image, it will happily tell me the correct answer:

```
rcv@mymachine:~$ docker images -a --digests docker.myregistry.net/myproject/myimage
REPOSITORY                                TAG          DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
docker.myregistry.net/myproject/myimage   8.0.0-rc9    sha256:56993a4bdf42a6337c1e9a32603c8758d9a67b42b525c18c6d500b8688f50c47   2198f19aede7   3 days ago     1.84GB
```

However, if I try asking *specifically* about the tag I'm interested in it will tell me that there's no digest.

```
rcv@mymachine:~$ docker images -a --digests docker.myregistry.net/myproject/myimage:8.0.0-rc9
REPOSITORY                                TAG         DIGEST    IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
docker.myregistry.net/myproject/myimage   8.0.0-rc9   <none>    2198f19aede7   3 days ago   1.84GB
```

I've been alternating between building this image locally, and just pulling it back down from the registry.  Is it possible that `docker images` is confused, or am I missing some subtle difference between the above two commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be a [bug in the docker CLI](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42439). This shouldn't have any impact on the underlying digest. If you know the image you want to query, it's probably easier to inspect that image for the digest:

```
$ docker image inspect nginx:latest --format '{{index .RepoDigests 0}}'
nginx@sha256:644a70516a26004c97d0d85c7fe1d0c3a67ea8ab7ddf4aff193d9f301670cf36
```